# Browser support for offline Event in 2022. Does Brave (or any browser) support the offline Event?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, cross-platform, offline, detection

I understand that browser support for the `navigator.onLine` Property and for the `online` and `offline` Events has changed over time but I'm currently very muddled over what does and doesn't work in 2022.

I have the following setup:

```
const checkAppConnection = (e) => {

  // SET UP BOOLEAN 
  let appConnected;

  // GIVE BOOLEAN A VALUE
  switch (true) {
 
    case (e.type === 'load'): appConnected = navigator.onLine;
    case (e.type === 'online'): appConnected = true;
    case (e.type === 'offline'): appConnected = false;

  if (appConnected) {
    console.log(navigator.onLine, appConnected, 'App is online');
  }

  else {
    console.log(navigator.onLine, appConnected, 'App is offline');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', checkAppConnection);
window.addEventListener('online', checkAppConnection);
window.addEventListener('offline', checkAppConnection);
```

I realised quite quickly that when I turn my WiFi off, the `offline` Event doesn't fire in **Firefox 100**.

So I tried the script in **Brave 101** and I was surprised to see that the `offline` Event doesn't fire in **Brave 101** either. (It should be the same as **Chrome 101** right?)

Is something wrong with the script above? How can I get the `offline` Event to fire?

---

**Further Reading:**

I found this, but Remy wrote it *over eleven years ago*:

- [Broken Offline Support](https://remysharp.com/2011/04/19/broken-offline-support) by *Remy Sharp*